# System.IO.Abstraction can't find IStreamWriter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to unit test a method that calls `StreamWriter`. I am trying to use `System.IO.Abstraction` in order to mock `StreamWriter` however I can't find the interface on the last NuGet looked into the source code as well but have no idea what is the replacement for this, other stuff like `FileInfo` is working as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: 1. Where did you see anything that says System.IO.Abstractions has an IStreamWriter interface? It doesn't appear to. 2. Why would you need an abstraction around StreamWriter, anyway? StreamWriter is already an abstraction -- it can work with any stream you give it. Just make your tests give it a MemoryStream instead of a FileStream.

Comment: usefull is this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480563/c-sharp-unit-test-a-streamwriter-parameter Or this could be usefull as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087351/how-do-you-mock-out-the-file-system-in-c-sharp-for-unit-testing

Comment: @JoeWhite probably from here. http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2012/09/28/abstracting-the-file-system/

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for how to mock a FileStream via System.IO.Abstractions and couldn't see it initially. It's Hanging off the FileInfo Object. It results in slightly clunky code and required a cast. My Original Code:

```csharp
FileStream fileStreamBack = null;
using (fileStreamBack = new FileStream(fileFrom, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var fileStreamf = new FileStream(fileTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
                fileStreamBack.CopyTo(fileStreamf);             // Use the .Net 
                fileStreamBack.Flush(); // Making sure
                fileStreamBack.Close(); // Making sure
}
```

Now Replaced with

```csharp
FileStream fileStreamBack = null;
using (fileStreamBack = (FileStream)_fileSystem.FileInfo.FromFileName(fileFrom).Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var fileStreamf = (FileStream)_fileSystem.FileInfo.FromFileName(fileTo).Open(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fileStreamBack.CopyTo(fileStreamf);             // Use the .Net 
            fileStreamBack.Flush(); // Making sure
            fileStreamBack.Close(); // Making sure
        }
```

There is also a MockFileStream object in the System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers (for our convenience!)

Comment: There is a slightly briefer way to get the filestream which I've shown in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Taking @BarryMcDermid's answer and altering it slightly you can do something along the lines of:

```csharp
using (Stream fs = _fileSystem.FileStream.Create(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    ms.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close(); 
}
```

By declaring the 'FileStream' as a `Stream` instead of a `FileStream` you'll then be able to use System.IO.Abstraction.TestingHelpers to test this code without getting exceptions.

There's a more fully worked example of that [in my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933069/system-io-abstraction-how-to-mock-filestream).