# unit testing a void method with StreamWriter as one of the parameters

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, automated-tests

I currently have a method like this

```
public void BusinessMethod(object value, StreamWriter sw)
{
    //Calls a private method that converts the data in `value` to a custom formatted string variable `str`
    string str = myPrivateMethod(value);

    //write the string to stream
    sw.Write(str);
}
```

I am trying to test this method using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12480609/20358) and have done exactly the same thing. However, my `result` string comes back as an empty string. I cannot change the method signature. How does one test a method like this? I am using Nunit for testing.

This is my test method

```
    [Test]
    public void My_Test()
    {
        MyPoco dto = new MyPoco ();
        //set up the dto properties here

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            sut.BusinessMethod(dto, writer);

            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the precise behavior you're attempting to validate?

Comment: I am trying to validate if the dto sent in to `BusinessMethod` gets written to the stream or not. that is all the `BusinessMethod` is responsible for.

Comment: Since your test has no assertions, it's not actually testing anything. Can you provide a minimal reproduction case that includes all of the relevant code?

Comment: You also mention that `actual` is empty but i don't see and actual. Do you mean `result`? Also, you need something like     Assert.AreEqual("Expected Result", result);

Comment: the assertion would be possible if the string `result` in the test method returned some value. Thats where I am stuck at the moment so not sure if I should be testing this method this way or not.

Comment: @GreatNate: Yes I meant result. Updated the question

Comment: Try flushing the streamwriter before reading the data from the stream.

Comment: That did it :) Thanks Lasse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Close`/`Flush`/`Dispose` writer so it actually commits changes to stream:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        sut.BusinessMethod(dto, writer);
    }
    // moved outside of inner using to ensure writer stored content to stream
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```